# tfs history show merge changesetids from other branch?

Tags: tfs, merge, history

We use tfs2010 and vs2010.

Suppose I have two branches (make it simple):
Development
Main

I made some changes on development branch, checked in and merged to Main branch.
On development branch I have changeset with id 00001.
On main branch I have changesetid with 100001.

If I will history from Main branch, I can see a changeset 10001 with all the merged files (which is good).

However, is it possible to see that changeset 00001 is the ones that got merged from development to main branch?

I tried tfpt history followbranches, but tfpt doesn't have history command any more as it is moved to tf.

I then tried tf but tf history command doesn't have followbranches option at all.

Can someone help?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 5):

In the history window of Main branch, Right Click on the Changeset (10001) and select "Track Changeset". After that select the Dev branch (in the Select Branches window) and then click the Visualize button at the bottom. You should see the window with the link between the Dev and Main changesets. You can view "Timeline Tracking" or "Hierarchy Tracking".

See below the link explaining it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd405662.aspx

Comment: Is this supported in tfs2010?

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario:**

1. Checked in `Dev` branch
2. Want to Confirm weather `Changeset` is merged to `QA` Branch

Below is taken from Microsoft [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/view-where-when-changesets-have-been-merged?view=azure-devops).

**To view the Tracking Changeset Window from the History window of a branch or file**

1. In **Source Control Explorer**, click a branch or a folder or file that is contained by a branch.
2. Click the **File** menu, point to **Source Control**, and then click **View History**.
3. In the **History** window, right-click the changeset that you want to view, and click **Track Changeset**.

The **Select Branches** dialog box appears.

4. (Optional) In the **Branches** list, select or clear the check boxes for the branches that you want to show or hide.

As you select or clear check boxes, a preview of your selections appears on the right-hand side of the dialog box.

5. (Optional) If your team has a lot of branches, click the buttons above the preview to select the branches that you want more easily.

You can move the pointer over each button to get information about what the button does.

6. Click **Visualize**.

I have tried this in **Visual Studio 2017**.

Hope this helps.